# CD4067BE Multiplexer input always observed at all outputs

Tags: multiplexer

i am trying to use CD4067BE to switch an input between to output pins. I used 15V/0V Vdd/Vss for the mux, and connected all selection inputs and inhibit to 0V (Vss). I get the input signal at all output pins. I tried changing one of the selection inputs to (5V),  but I still have the signal at all outputs?

Could you tell me what is wrong?

[image]

Comment: *Could you tell me what is wrong?* Sure but not without you showing a schematic of what you're talkign about.

Comment: Try adding a small load to the outputs (e.g. 100k to 1M resistor)

Comment: Also, what signal are you feeding in.

Comment: @FakeMoustache diagram is added

Comment: @TomCarpenter  my input is from current source giving 20mA current. Regarding the load I have tried measuring the output with 100k ohm and also without load. signal is found at every output pin.

Comment: If you applied a Voltage greater than Vcc or greater than 5mA at any time or ignored  EOS/ESD awareness to static damage, the part may be damaged and normally open ports may be shorted when only one port is selected.

Comment: nna: Are you saying that you are connecting a 20 mA current source to a CMOS logic input pin? BTW: You did not label the pin name on the 4067 into which you are feeding the "Input 0-15V. Next, you are telling us it is NOT a 0-15 Volt signal, but rather a 20 mA "current source". You must be very specific and unambiguous in your question, if you expect to get a meaningful answer.

Comment: @FiddyOhm yes I am using this Mux to switch input current signal of 20mA between output pins. I have fixed the diagram

Comment: nna: And what are you expecting to see on the various outputs as the 4067 address/select lines are changed to their 16 combinations? What is the voltage compliance of the "current source" (which is not shown in your diagram)? What is the output voltage of the current source when it is open-circuited? Do the current source and the 15 volt supply to the 4067 share the same DC common/ground?

Comment: @FiddyOhm i expect input current signal to appear at different output pins when I change the address/select lines. open-circuit voltage of the current source is 100V. Both current source and MUX share the same supply (15v) and common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> open-circuit voltage of the current source is 100V

You are operating your CD4067B outside the allowed limits, and you might have permanently damaged it. The *absolute maximum* voltage allowed on any input is \$V_{DD} + 0.5V\$ (you have stated that you are using \$V_{DD} = 15V\$).

From the TI CD4067B [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4067b.pdf):

[image: extract from TI CD4067B datasheet showing max input voltage]

Also you said:

> I tried changing one of the selection inputs to (5V)

When you have \$V_{DD} = 15V\$, then \$5V\$ is not a logic 1! Again, from the datasheet, with \$V_{DD} = 15V\$ then \$V_{IH\space Minimum} = 11V\$

[image: extract from TI CD4067B datasheet showing logic level thresholds]

Comment: Any idea on how to limit the current-source open-circuit voltage such it does not exceed 15V, but without increasing the series load?

Comment: @n.na: I think you've got the answer to your original question. Post a new one to find a solution and give some context. You wasted some peoples' time by not disclosing relevant details (100 V into a 15 V chip) on this question.

Comment: @n.na - As *Transistor* says, that would be a new question. Before considering a possible solution, readers would probably want to understand more context and details about the problem you are trying to solve, what devices are being used for sending & receiving, what solutions you have considered and why, whether the "input" current signal is analogue or a discrete logic signal with only 2 levels of current etc.